# How to show only filtered data in a table

Tags: swift

How to show the data thats `decks.status == true`, and ignore those objects set to false?

data:

```
var decks: [DeckOfCards]
```

What I've got now:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

    if (thedeck.decks[indexPath.row].status == true) {
        cell.label.text = "\(thedeck.decks[indexPath.row].card.name)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. By the time you get to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you're already stated that a cell should be dequeued for this index path (and therefore at this index in your data array). The right place to be doing this filtering is in your data source.

For example, in addition to your `decks` array, you could make a computed property (`filteredDecks`) that gets its value by filtering the `decks` array.

```
var decks = [DeckOfCards]
var filteredDecks: [DeckOfCards] {
    return decks.filter { $0.status }
}
```

You can then use this property as the data source for your table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredDecks.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.label.text = "\(filteredDecks[indexPath.row].card.name)"

    return cell
}
```

Now since this solution computes the `filteredDecks` array on each property access, it may not be the best approach if `decks` is a large array, or if you're reloading the table view frequently. If this is the case, and it's possible to do so, you should prefer filtering the `decks` array ahead of time using the same method shown in the computed property above.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the filter function on the decks

```
let filteredDecks = decks.filter({$0.status})
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter your array as

```
   self.decks = self.decks.filter {
          (d: DeckOfCards) -> Bool in
          return d.status == true
    }
```

Now your array will have the filtered values. you dont need to check for `status` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function.